# Sudden Error, System won't boot up

Tags: error-handling

I was running

> sudo shred -vfuzn *

command in a particular directory which was not part of vital directory structure.

when suddenly my file system gave me an I/O error, after reboot following log is displayed.

[image]

Is it possible to recover system without any data loss?

Comment: I am not sure if you would lose data. If you do not have very important stuff on it i would give it a try. It would never (if it happens) delete a lot if i am right.

Comment: What was that directory? If there are symlinks to something like /dev/sda, then you might have run into deep trouble if you don't have backups.

Comment: I appreciate​ your answer but what should I Give a try to, I am in a situation right now I didn't ask for suggestions. I need solution for my problem which is shown in the log image.

Comment: So, try running what is says on the screen `fsck /dev/sda5` as that is saying that it has inconsistencies.

Comment: Yes, please do as @Terrance said

Comment: @Terrance It works!!!!  thanks. I didn't run that command correctly. There were some bitmap instances going wrong and some orphaned inodes, fixed it now running well. What I don't understand is, what did I do to trigger that situation?!

Comment: @AndroidDev Yeah I did, everything is fine now but I don't understand why/how did I get into this situation.

Comment: @Lekensteyn I am sure that the directory didn't have had access to any vitals I created that directory specifically to shred some stuff. I don't think it can access (.) or (..) i.e. parent directory up to root. Also I don't know if that command is safe now.

Comment: In all honesty, I am not really sure what you might have done to trigger that.  I work around thousands of servers all the time and there are instances where servers might hiccup and something goes haywire and all they want to do is to boot to Maintenance mode and we have to run fsck on them to fix them.  I guess the idea is that we have to be careful in what we do.  From what you are saying in your post, it really doesn't look like you did anything wrong.  Just something happened to cause your inconsistency.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks its a nice piece of Advice from an experienced person like you. That means I can restart the shredding process again? also if you are writing an answer please mention working of fsck command.

Answer (score 1):

It specifically says right their what to do: type `fsck /dev/sda5`.  Type that into the shell their and press enter.  Update the question if you need more help.